# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method en php

Tags: php

Buenas tardes tengo un detalle con este código, estoy usando prestashop 1.7 y uso una herramienta de monitoreo para ver que todo funcione bien, esta herramienta me detecta un error de php que dice lo siguiente:

**Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method advancedspeed::get_domain_prefix() in /var/www/html/modules/advancedspeed/controllers/front/image.php:132 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/classes/controller/Controller.php(292): AdvancedSpeedimageModuleFrontController->initContent() #1 /var/www/html/classes/Dispatcher.php(515): ControllerCore->run() #2 /var/www/html/index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #3 {main} throw**

los archivos son los siguientes:

image.php

```
if($tp['object_type'] == 'product' || empty($tp['object_type'] ))
            {
                foreach($langs as $l)
                {
                    $product = new Product($tp['object_id'], false, $l['id_lang']);
                    $images = $product->getImages($l['id_lang']);
                    foreach($images as $image)
                    {
                        $imageLink = advancedspeed::get_domain_prefix().$link->getImageLink($product->link_rewrite, $image['id_image'], $image_type);
                        $imageLink = str_replace('.webp', '.jpg', $imageLink);
                        $optimized_image = advancedspeed::get_optimized_image($imageLink, $quality );
                
                        if (!isset($optimized_image['error'])) 
                        {    
                            if(isset($optimized_image['percent']))
                            {
                                if((int)$optimized_image['percent'] > 0)
                                {
                                    $image_old = new Image($image['id_image']);
```

[image: image.php]

Controller.php

```
    if ($this->checkAccess()) {
        // setMedia MUST be called before postProcess
        if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_header || (isset($this->className) && $this->className))) {
            $this->setMedia();
        }

        // postProcess handles ajaxProcess
        $this->postProcess();

        if (!empty($this->redirect_after)) {
            $this->redirect();
        }

        if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_header || (isset($this->className) && $this->className))) {
            $this->initHeader();
        }

        if ($this->viewAccess()) {
            $this->initContent();
        } else {
            $this->errors[] = $this->trans('Access denied.', array(), 'Admin.Notifications.Error');
        }

        if (!$this->content_only && ($this->display_footer || (isset($this->className) && $this->className))) {
            $this->initFooter();
        }
```

[image: Controller.php]

Dispatcher.php

```
  // Instantiate controller
    try {
        // Loading controller
        $controller = Controller::getController($controller_class);

        // Execute hook dispatcher
        if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher)) {
            Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
        }

        // Running controller
        $controller->run();

        // Execute hook dispatcher after
        if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher)) {
            Hook::exec('actionDispatcherAfter', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
        }
    } catch (PrestaShopException $e) {
        $e->displayMessage();
    }
}
```

[image: Dispatcher]

index.php

```
<?php
   require dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php';
   Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema está en la clase `advancespeed`, que no tiene el método `get_domain_prefix()`.

Comment: Hola @Triby es que todo esta encerrado en esta clase `class AdvancedSpeedimageModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{` ¿te refieres a esa? ¿como podría poner el prefijo?

Comment: Me refiero a: `advancedspeed::get_domain_prefix()` esa línea es la que provoca el error porque no existe el método en esa clase, probablemente lo tienes en otra.

Comment: Estas seguro que el nombre de la clase es advancespeed o AdvancedSpeed es decir, con la A mayúscula, por convención los nombres de las clases deben escribirse en PascalCase. Además recuerda que php es case sensitive así que pendiente con ese detalle.